# MS Accessで複数選択可のコンボボックスに VBA にて指定した項目をチェックする方法

Tags: ms-access, vba

表題の通りなのですが、複数選択可にするとどうすれば VBA 上からコンボボックスに指定した項目をチェックするのか分かりません。

VBA に慣れていないこともあり、まったく的外れな方法でやろうとしたのか、

1. 選択用関数があるのでは？
2. `.Value` が配列だから配列を追加してやればいいのでは？
3. ２が駄目だったから別の配列を用意して入れ替えるのは？

の三本立てで攻めてみましたが、駄目でした。

実現方法をご存知の方はアドバイスをよろしくお願いいたします。

---

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]  
*上図: テーブルの設計*

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]  
*上図: フォームの内容*

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]  
*上図: VBAサブルーチンの内容*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の様にすればいいと思います。

```vb
タグ.Value = Array("ゴリラ")
```

複数の場合は以下の様にします

```vb
タグ.Value = Array("ズック","ゴリラ")
```

ただし、存在しなくてもアイテムが増えてチェックがついてしまうので、存在しないアイテムを追加しないように気を付けてください。

```vb
タグ.Value = Array("たぶん無いだろうと思うアイテム")
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

**コメントに書いた部分の検証コード**

大した内容ではないですが、コメントだと読みにくいのでコードにしました。
試す場合は意味ディエイトウィンドウを表示しておいてください。

```vb
Private Sub コマンド7_Click()

    Debug.Print "* Sample1 *"
    Call Sample1(Me![タグ].Value, Me![タグ].Value)
    Debug.Print "--"
    Debug.Print "Result: " & UBound(Me![タグ].Value) ' 結果は増えない

    Dim aMyArr() As Variant
    ReDim aMyArr(2)

    Debug.Print "* Sample2 *"
    Call Sample2(aMyArr, aMyArr)
    Debug.Print "--"
    Debug.Print "Result: " & UBound(aMyArr)  ' 結果も増える
End Sub

Public Sub Sample1(ByRef a1 As Variant, ByRef a2 As Variant)
    'ByRef a1() as Variant では受け取れない

    Debug.Print "Before :" & UBound(a1)  ' (A)

    ReDim Preserve a1(UBound(a1) + 1)

    Debug.Print "After1 :" & UBound(a1)  ' (A) + 1 の値
    Debug.Print "After2 :" & UBound(a2)  ' (A) と同じ値

End Sub

Public Sub Sample2(ByRef a1() As Variant, ByRef a2() As Variant)
    ' ByRef a1 As Variant でも受け取れる（結果は同じ）。

    Debug.Print "Before :" & UBound(a1)  ' (B)

    ReDim Preserve a1(UBound(a1) + 1)

    Debug.Print "After1 :" & UBound(a1)  ' (B) + 1 の値
    Debug.Print "After2 :" & UBound(a2)  ' (B) + 1 の値(変更に追随している）

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

このように修正すると正常に動作しました。配列のサイズを拡張する時はRedim Preserveを使うんですね。
まだひとつ疑問が残ってまして、'コントロールのValueを直接触ると内容が変わらないのですが、VBAはこういうものなのでしょうか？

```
Private Sub Btnゴリラにチェック_Click()
  'これだと動く
  Dim arr()
  arr = Me![タグ].Value
  If Not InArray("ゴリラ",arr) Then Call ArrayPush(arr, "ゴリラ")
  [タグ].Value = arr

  'これだと動かない
  'If Not InArray("ゴリラ",Me![タグ].Value) Then Call ArrayPush(Me![タグ].Value, "ゴリラ")
End Sub
```

標準モジュール

```
Public Sub ArrayPush(ByRef arr, val)
  Dim cnt
  cnt = UBound(arr) + 1
  ReDim Preserve arr(cnt)
  arr(cnt) = val
End Sub

Public Function InArray(val, arr)
  Dim re As Variant
  re = Filter(arr, val)

  If UBound(re) <> -1 Then
    InArray = True
  Else
    InArray = False
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Valueプロパティが返してくるのは配列そのものではなくてSAFEARRAY構造体かなにかだったように思います。（なのでArrayPushの引数を `ByRef arr() as Variant`とはできない。）
正確性は自信ないですが、結局ArrayPushのarrに渡されているのも構造体のコピー（？）であるため、arrの変更はタグ.Valueには関係ありません。
たとえば、ArrayPushの引数を増やして、それにもタグ.Valueを渡したとします。arrをRedimしても新しい引数の要素数は変わりません。
これがただの動的配列(Dim a() As Variant) だった場合は、二つの引数は両方とも影響を受けます。
また、普通の配列(`Dim myArray() as Variant`)の様に宣言したものであればByRefで渡してReDimすれば元の内容も変わります。

Comment: コメントが長くてわかりにくかったので、回答の方にコードを追記しました。